# Raising element of field to characteristic power

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I came across this in a set of notes.

> Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $\lambda\in K$. Then $$\lambda^{p-1}=1.$$

I've never seen this before. Is it correct?

Comment: I doubt this is true in general. (Counter-example: in $\mathbf F_p(X)$, do we have  $X^k=1$ for any $k>0$?). What is the context?

Comment: No. The silly case is $0^{p-1}=0$.
More deeply, for $\lambda$ in a finite field $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ you have $\lambda^{p-1}=1\iff \lambda\in \Bbb F_p\setminus\{0\}$. With a bit more machinery, this can be proved true for any extension of $\Bbb F_p$ in place of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant fact here is that, for any field $F$ of characteristic $p$, there is a unique field homomorphism $\mathbf{F}_p \to F$, and that the nonzero elements of (the image of) $\mathbf{F}_p$ are precisely the $(p-1)$-th roots of unity in $F$.

$\mathbf{F}_p$ means the field of $p$ elements, which is isomorphic to the integers modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you gave is "known" (i.e. when stated correctly, see the comments or the link) and is called [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it isn't true-it is known (but I shall not prove it here) that in a field, $F$, that a polynomial of degree $n$ in $F[x]$ has at most $n$ roots.

If $\text{char}(F) = p$, we certainly have: $x^p - x$ is a polynomial of degree $p$ in $F[x]$, and this factors in the prime field of $F$ (which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$) as:

$x^p - x = x(x - 1)\cdots(x - (p - 1))$ (which should be clear since $\Bbb Z_p - \{0\}$ is a group of order $p - 1$, and thus every non-zero element has (multiplicative) order dividing $p-1$, from basic group theory).

So if $F \neq \Bbb Z_p$ (or more properly, is (strictly) larger than its prime subfield), we cannot have any other roots of $x^p - x = x(x^{p-1} - 1)$, so no roots of $x^{p-1} - 1$ other than the ones in the prime subfield.

Concretely, if $F$ is a field of $4$ elements, say $\{0,1,a,1+a\}$, of characteristic $2$, then $a \in F$, but $a = a^1 = a^{2-1} \neq 1$.